# What does the expression tend to?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let a function defined on the real line be differentiable at the real number $1$. As the integer tends to infinity, what does the expression $f (1+1/n^2)+f(1+2/n^2)+⋅⋅⋅f(1+n/n^2)- nf(1)$ tend to?
My answer is $0$, since each term gets multiplied by $0$. I got this by distributing the $nf(1)$ between the other $n$ terms. And, since the the function is differentiable at $1$, it is a bounded quantity which multiplied by $0$ each time. Is my answer correct?

Comment: What happens if $f(x) = x$? What about $2x$? (Find a closed form expression for a fixed $n$, simplify as much as you can, and _then_ let $n \to \infty$) From there, you should be able to make a pretty good guess as to what the answer is.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the first derivative is continuous at $1$,  and apply the mean value theorem:

$$f(1+a) = f(1) + a f'(c),$$

where $c$ is between $1$ and $1+a$. Then we have

$$ \mbox{sum} = n f(1) + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{n^2} f'(c_j)-n f(1) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^n j f'(c_j)=(*)$$

Now

$f'(c_j) = f'(1) + f'(c_j) - f'(1)$. Therefore,

$$(*) = \frac{f'(1)}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n j + R_n,$$

where $$R_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^n j \left(f'(c_j) - f'(1)\right).$$

Now,

$$\sum_{j=1}^n j = \frac{(1+n)n}{2},$$

and as for $R_n$, or each $j$, $|c_j-1| \le 1/n$, so it follows that $$|f'(c_j)-f'(1)|\le \epsilon_n = \sup_{1<x<1+1/n} |f'(x) -f'(1)|.$$

Since $f'$ is continuous at $1$, $\epsilon_n\to 0$. Thus,

$$|R_n|< \epsilon_n \frac{(1+n)n}{2n^2}\to 0,\mbox{ as }n\to\infty.$$

It follows that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (*) = \frac{f'(1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, your answer is not correct. You basically said that" $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = 0$ since $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} a_n = 0$"; which is false.

One way to do this is to use the Taylor series (you mention that the function is differentiable, that should probably be used):

$\frac{n^2}{i}(f(1+\frac{i}{n^2})-f(1)) = f'(1) + o(\frac{i}{n^2}) $

$f(1+\frac{i}{n^2})-f(1) = \frac{i}{n^2}f'(1) + o(\frac{i^2}{n^4}) = \frac{i}{n^2}f'(1) + o(\frac{1}{n^2}) $

$\sum_{i=1}^n  f(1+\frac{i}{n^2})-f(1) = (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2}f'(1)) + o(\frac{1}{n}) $

So it has the same limit as $ (f'(1)\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2}) = f'(1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}$

I let you finish

Comment: What should be the correct approach?